# Compiler tools, execv and "exec format error" under s390x chroot

Tags: linux, debian, chroot, g++

I have a Debian 8 x86_64 machine with two chroot environments. The first is *`armel`* and the second is *`s390x`*. *`armel`* was installed last week, and *`s390x`* was installed recently. *`armel`* is fine both before and after the *`s390x`* install. But I'm catching errors when compiling under the newly installed *`s390x`*.

```
# chroot debian-s390x
# g++ -dumpmachine
s390x-linux-gnu

# cd /home/cryptopp-5.6.3/

# make
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -pipe -c osrng.cpp
g++: error trying to exec '/usr/lib/gcc/s390x-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus': execv: Exec format error
GNUmakefile:382: recipe for target 'osrng.o' failed
make: *** [osrng.o] Error 1
```

I can't find any information when searching for *`/usr/lib/gcc/s390x-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus': execv: Exec format error`*.

I did find some reading related to `cc1plus`, but I don't see where there's a problem with the installation:

```
# file /usr/lib/gcc/s390x-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus
/usr/lib/gcc/s390x-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus: ELF 64-bit MSB executable, IBM S/390, version 1
(GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32,
BuildID[sha1]=aaa1e442e47e5e41c36b70d5e6a8f538da4ca3e7, not stripped
```

I also performed a reinstall of *`g++`* with `apt-get install --reinstall g++`, but it did not help.

What is the issue, and what is the solution?

---

**EDIT**: this may be the issue, or may be a related issue: [Debian Bug 684909: qemu-system-s390x is broken, no bootloader 's390-zipl.rom'](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=684909).

---

I don't believe its due to the project I am trying to compile:

```c++
# cat test.cxx 
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  return argc;
}

# g++ test.cxx 
g++: error trying to exec '/usr/lib/gcc/s390x-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus': execv: Exec format error
```

---

Here is the 5-second tour of the procedure to install the *debian-s390x* environment:

```
# apt-get install qemu-user-static debootstrap
# qemu-debootstrap --arch=s390x --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg
  --variant=buildd --exclude=debfoster unstable debian-s390x http://ftp.debian.org/debian
# chroot debian-s390x
# apt-get install locales build-essentials emacs-nox
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with binfmt registrations. Taking from Michael Tokarev's message in [Debian Issue 799120: cc1/cc1plus fails with "execv: exec format error” under QEMU s390x, can't compile C++ program](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=799120):

> This has been fixed in the version which you reported this prob against,
>   1:2.4+dfsg-3, where I updated the binfmt masks to include OSABI_GNU too.
>   This was #784605.
>
> However, it looks like we've a problem with updating binfmt registrations.
>   If you had qemu-user-static package previously installed (which registers
>   only OSABI_SYSV variant) and update it to current version (which should
>   register both SYSV and GNU variants), the in-kernel registration isn't
>   updated.  It will be updated at reboot, or you can remove and reinstall
>   qemu-user-static package, after which it'll work.